# How do the letters/numbers appear bigger?

Tags: numbering, titlesec, letters, sections-paragraphs

Can we change something at the command

```
\titleformat{\section}{\bf}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

so that the letters of a section and its number appear a little bigger?

Comment: @HarishKumar Write a proper answer, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `\titleformat` is  (page 4 of `titlesec` manual)

```
\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

The descriptions for all these may be found in the manual. The second mandatory argument is of interest to you. The formatting commands used here will be applied to both section number and title. So you can write

```
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Note that two letter commands like `\bf` shouldn't be used. Here `\LARGE` may be changed as you wish.  The default values are

```
\titleformat{\section}
          {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
  \section{Here}
\end{document}
```

[image]